# inheritance in java - compilation fails

Tags: java

This question was part of the OCJP and I am getting option A (alpha beta) but the answer is E (compilation fails). Don't understand how did it happen.

Can someone please explain ?

```
class Alpha {
     String getType() { return "alpha"; }
}
class Beta extends Alpha {
    String getType() { return "beta"; }
}
class Gamma extends Beta {
    String getType() { return "gamma"; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gamma g1 = new Alpha();
        Gamma g2 = new Beta();
        System.out.println(g1.getType() + " "  + g2.getType());
    }
}
```

What is the result?

- A) alpha beta
- B) beta beta
- C) gamma gamma
- D) alpha alpha
- E) Compilation fails.

Comment: Did you read the compiler error?

Comment: Look at the hierarchy, read the compiler error, look back at the hierarchy, find out the answer by yourself, learn.

Comment: Pretty sure `Gamma g1 = new Alpha();` needs to be `Alpha g1 = new Gamma();`

Comment: You can't declare a subclass variable and then instantiate a class more super to it. You can do it the other way round though. So, in this instance, compilation would fail, so E.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Answer is E => compilation is supposed to fail.

Comment: @JornVernee Yup. I'm saying the OP was looking at the hierarchy backwards.

Answer (score 2):

The inheritance hierarchy indicates:

- `Beta` **is-an** `Alpha`
- `Gamma` **is-a** `Beta`

However, that doesn't imply that `Alpha` or `Beta` is a `Gamma`, hence compilation fails due to your attempt to assign an instance of either `Alpha` or `Beta` to `Gamma`.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a class, but declare it as a more super class, but not the other way around.

In very simple terms, a Ferrari is a type of car, but a car is not a type of Ferrari. A banana is a type of fruit, but a fruit is not a type of banana.

Hence...

```
Alpha test1 = new Gamma();
Beta test2 = new Gamma();
Alpha test3 = new Beta();
```

... would be fine, as you are instantiating a Gamma (or Beta) object, but only allowing access via the defined Alpha and Beta interfaces in their base classes. It is only allowable via entirely shared interfaces. A Gamma is a type of Alpha, or a type of Beta. And a Beta is a type of Alpha also. But an Alpha is not a type of Gamma, nor is a Beta a type of Gamma.

However, an Alpha or Beta object does not share all the methods of a Gamma object, so you simply can't do it that way.

```
Gamma test = new Alpha(); // compilation error

// or...
Gamma test = new Beta(); // compilation error
```

As you are trying to access an Alpha or Beta object via a Gamma interface and those objects do not have that interface.